# Как спарсить товары с сайта где товары подгружаются динамически?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Делаю парсер интернет магазина на python, написал скрипт который загружает ссылки на страницы с карточками товара,  с основной страницы, для дальнейшего парсинга. Столкнулся с проблемой парсятся только только первый 15 ссылок, остальные которые появляются при скроллинге страницы не отображаются. Как решить эту проблему?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re,csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = 'https://kingfashion.com/ru/girls-sugar-squad/'

def get_html(url):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    response = urlopen(req).read()
    return response

def parse_url(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'category-products'})
    rows = table.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-info'})

    projects = []
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('h2')
        projects.append({
            'title': cols[0].text,
            'url': cols[0].a['href']

        })
    return projects

def save_url(projects,path):
    with open(path,'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(('Название', 'URL'))
        writer.writerows(
            (project['title'],project['url']) for project in projects
        )



def main():
    all_url = parse_url(get_html(BASE_URL))
    save_url(all_url, 'url.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Достать запрос, который подгружает, и парсить его

Comment: Можете подсказать что использовать, чтобы написать такой запрос?

Comment: Встроенные в любой браузер инструменты для разработки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему используя Selenium WebDriver

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re,csv

import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


BASE_URL = 'https://kingfashion.com/ru/boys-riot-club/'



def get_html(url):
    # req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    # response = urlopen(req).read()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 3

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    return driver.page_source

def parse_url(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'category-products'})
    rows = table.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-info'})

    projects = []
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('h2')
        projects.append({
            'title': cols[0].text,
            'url': cols[0].a['href']

        })
    return projects

def save_url(projects,path):
    with open(path,'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(('Название', 'URL'))
        writer.writerows(
            (project['title'],project['url']) for project in projects
        )



def main():
    all_url = parse_url(get_html(BASE_URL))
    save_url(all_url, 'url.csv')
    # get_html(BASE_URL)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам надо покопаться в js-файлах на том сайте и найти функцию/метод, который отвечает за загрузку товаров. Далее надо определить в этом коде к какому скрипту он обращается и какие переменные передает. Там обязательно должны быть параметры отступа (offset) или постраничной разбивки (pagination). Также может быть количество загружаемых товаров (limit). Могут быть переменные роутинга (если скрипт один на все или группу ajax-методов), типа location, section, action и т.д.

Далее сам HTML сайта  вам уже не требуется. Просто обращаетесь к тому скрипту и передаете ему список переменных для выполнения запроса и получаете все в формате JSON. В подавляющем большинстве случаев (99%) никакой защиты там не стоит, но в некоторых случаях все же могут быть подводные камни, типа подписи к запросу или проверки на User Agent.

Данные можно брать через cURL или любой другой метод, который обеспечивает сетевое взаимодействие. Там надо будет выставить тип запроса GET/POST (в зависимости от того, каким способом работает скрипт), а также желательно User Agent. Если стоят количественные и частотные ограничения - регулируем частоту обращений скрипта или используем proxy.